# For looping forever

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Trying to make a simple bit of JS that sets a random background color, and then creates i dots at random locations. However, it makes infinite dots in sets of i. So if I set i < 10, it makes 10 dots at a time.

Coding with the p5 library in sublime.

```
function setup() {
     r = random(0,255);
     g = random(0,255);
     b = random(0,255);
     createCanvas(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
     background(r,g,b);
     frameRate(1);
}

function draw() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        fill(0);
        noStroke();
        ellipse(random(0, width), random(0, height), 80,80);
        }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? what is your desired goal? it's not clear

Comment: The `for` loop is not going to accomplish what you want in this case. You should probably take a step back and learn some of the fundamentals of JavaScript, specifically loops, timeouts, and recursion. There are loads of resources here and elsewhere for you to explore. Good luck!

Comment: @CalvinNunes I think the question was reasonably clear. The OP is asking why is he getting infinite dots drawn and how to correct it. It was clear enough that I wrote and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The draw() function is called on every frame by the p5 framework. As a result of this you are creating a new set of dots in every frame. You should create the (x, y) locations for the dots outside of the draw function, store them in an array and then only render them inside the draw function.

```
var dots = []; 

function setup() {
    r = random(0,255);
    g = random(0,255);
    b = random(0,255);
    createCanvas(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
    background(r,g,b);
    frameRate(1);
    createDots();
}

function createDots() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var dot = {
            x : random(0, width),
            y : random(0, height)
        };
        dots.push(dot);
    }
}

function draw() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        fill(0);
        noStroke();
        var dot = dots[i];
        ellipse(dot.x, dot.y, 80, 80);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks heaps !